# I'm a beginner, how should I implement this javascript code?

Tags: javascript

I found this code on google, this code is said to enable seeking in html 5 video, I'm a complete beginner and I'm stuck in this:

```
seekToTime:function( value )
{
    var seekToTime = this.videoPlayer.currentTime + value;
    if( seekToTime < 0 || seekToTime > this.videoPlayer.duration ) 
        return;

    this.videoPlayer.currentTime = seekToTime;
}
```

I have tried, modifying it like this but doesn't work,

```
seekToTime:function( value )

    {
        var videoPlayer = document.getElementById("videoplayer");
        var seekToTime = this.videoPlayer.currentTime + value;
        if( seekToTime < 0 || seekToTime > this.videoPlayer.duration ) 
            return;

        this.videoPlayer.currentTime = seekToTime;
    }
```

When I implement the modified code in the `head` of my html, the videos won't play at all. Please tell me how should I implement it, thanks...

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to access `this.videoPlayer` where `this` refers to the Window object and you have not declared videoPlayer on the window. Instead, you will need to modify:

```
var seekToTime = this.videoPlayer.currentTime + value;
```

to:

```
var seekToTime = videoPlayer.currentTime + value;
```

And any other references to `this.videoPlayer` should become `videoPlayer`.
The variable `videoPlayer` is able to be accessed, since you have declared it as a local variable to your function in the first line.

Comment: I tried your code but the videos still won't play, here's the code I tried: http://pastebin.com/51PF7WYM